# Why doesn't jQuery carousel work with an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

I tried making several jQuery content slider and carousel scripts, working with iframe, without success.

The iframe contains Google charts and are generated by a Ruby plugin ( [google_visualr](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr) )... you can see what HTML is generated :

```
  <div class='carousel_charts'>
    <ul>
      <li id='bar_chart'>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
            var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn('date', 'Date');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Refinery');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Locomotive');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Comf. Mexican Sofa');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Nesta');data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 21)}, {v: 123}, {v: 3}, {v: 16}, {v: 12}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 22)}, {v: 130}, {v: 1}, {v: 9}, {v: 22}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 23)}, {v: 155}, {v: 2}, {v: 15}, {v: 8}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 24)}, {v: 118}, {v: 3}, {v: 3}, {v: 11}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 25)}, {v: 99}, {v: 2}, {v: 7}, {v: 11}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 26)}, {v: 58}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 16}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2011, 10, 27)}, {v: 45}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 5}]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('bar_chart'));
            chart.draw(data_table, {width: 860, height: 540, title: 'Ruby CMS Diffusion', vAxis: {title: 'Last week', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}, oAxis: {title: 'RubyGems Downloads', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}});
          }});
        </script>

      </li>
      <li id='geo_chart'>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: function() {
            var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn('string', 'Country');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');data_table.addRow([{v: 'Germany'}, {v: 200}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'United States'}, {v: 300}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'Brazil'}, {v: 400}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'Canada'}, {v: 500}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'France'}, {v: 600}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'RU'}, {v: 700}]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geo_chart'));
            chart.draw(data_table, {width: 860, height: 540});
          }});
        </script>
      </li>
      <li id='scatter_chart'>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
            var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn('number', 'Age');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Weight');data_table.addRow([{v: 8}, {v: 12}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 4}, {v: 5.5}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 11}, {v: 14}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 4}, {v: 4.5}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 3}, {v: 3.5}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 6.5}, {v: 7}]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('scatter_chart'));
            chart.draw(data_table, {width: 860, height: 540, title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison', hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15}, vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15}, legend: 'none'});
          }});
        </script>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

... here it is the same code seen from [FireBug](http://pastie.org/2929234).

I want to slide the three google `<script type='text/javascript'>` injected into respective selectors `<li id='bar_chart'> <li id='geo_chart'> <li id='scatter_chart'>` ( see the previous code ).

I'm trying to use this [jQuery carousel script](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) to slide html iframe contents but it doesn't works. The js is the following :

```
$(function(){
  // Looping carousel
  $("div.carousel_charts").carousel( { autoSlide: true, pagination: true } );
});
```

which is based on [jquery.carousel.min.js](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/js/jquery.carousel.min.js). I'm currently using Rails-3.1.3 but pipelining works fine and this seems a more general js issue.

No idea of what's wrong with that ( but I'm not a 'frontend developer' )

Any Idea ?

Comment: I might be missing something but looking at your firebug output I don't see any sources defined. Are you trying to load the mentioned graph inside those iframes?

Comment: yes and the result is a page with three charts displayed one after another but not in the carousel. Note that the first code snipped in the post, is actually the same analyzed by Firebug, but extracted by clicking "View Page Source" of Firefox browser ( here it is the full page : http://pastie.org/2929692 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luca,

From what i've seen after playing with the code you've passed in question, you can solve the issue by specifying some elements' sizes with the CSS like this:

```
<style>
  #bar_chart, #geo_chart, #scatter_chart {
     height: 320px;
     width: 240px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
  }
  .carousel_charts ul {
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
  }
  .carousel-wrap {
     width: 240px;
  }
</style>
```

After applying above rules there is no need of specifying Google Chart size, so you can skip `{width: 860; height: 540}` from any `chart.draw()` call. Here is my result page code for your reference: http://pastebin.com/x0tpz1dq

*Please note - chart sizes are changed for illustration purpose.*

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, instead of using `jQuery(document).ready()` *function*, use the `window.load()` function to **initialize the carousel**, make sure the below code is in the same file which is used under iframe.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
   jQuery('.mycarousel').jcarousel({     
   });
});
```

*See also:*
[$(window).load and (document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352607/window-load-and-document-ready)