# $(window).load and (document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm  editing a template, but I know zero about javascript. On one page there is a slider, to load the slider there is a javascript using (document).ready.

On another page of the template there is another function $(window).load the filters some elements on the page.

I would like to make a page with both this elements: the slider and, below, the elements with the buttons to filter them.

I have copied the html and the javascript of the slider on the secon page, but I have noticed that the 2 javascript "kill each other": if both are present, the filering script does not work. If I remove the code to lod the slider, then the filtering function work perfectly. How can I fix the probem?

here is the code:

Slider:

```
//Revolution Slider
var tpj = jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function () {

    if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal != undefined)
        tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

    tpj('.fullwidthbanner').revolution(
        {
            delay: 9000,
            startwidth: 1920,
            startheight: 649,
            onHoverStop: "off",                      // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off
            thumbWidth: 100,                         // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
            thumbHeight: 50,
            thumbAmount: 3,
            hideThumbs: 0,
            navigationType: "bullet",                // bullet, thumb, none
            navigationArrows: "none",                // nexttobullets, solo (old name verticalcentered), none
            navigationStyle: "round",                // round,square,navbar,round-old,square-old,navbar-old, or any from the list in the docu (choose between 50+ different item), custom
            navigationHAlign: "center",              // Vertical Align top,center,bottom
            navigationVAlign: "bottom",                  // Horizontal Align left,center,right
            navigationHOffset: 30,
            navigationVOffset: 40,
            soloArrowLeftHalign: "left",
            soloArrowLeftValign: "center",
            soloArrowLeftHOffset: 20,
            soloArrowLeftVOffset: 0,
            soloArrowRightHalign: "right",
            soloArrowRightValign: "center",
            soloArrowRightHOffset: 20,
            soloArrowRightVOffset: 0,
            touchenabled: "on",                      // Enable Swipe Function : on/off
            stopAtSlide: -1,                         // Stop Timer if Slide "x" has been Reached. If stopAfterLoops set to 0, then it stops already in the first Loop at slide X which defined. -1 means do not stop at any slide. stopAfterLoops has no sinn in this case.
            stopAfterLoops: -1,                      // Stop Timer if All slides has been played "x" times. IT will stop at THe slide which is defined via stopAtSlide:x, if set to -1 slide never stop automatic
            hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,                   // It Defines if a caption should be shown under a Screen Resolution ( Basod on The Width of Browser)
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,               // Hide all The Captions if Width of Browser is less then this value
            hideSliderAtLimit: 0,                    // Hide the whole slider, and stop also functions if Width of Browser is less than this value
            fullWidth: "on",
            shadow: 0                                //0 = no Shadow, 1,2,3 = 3 Different Art of Shadows -  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)
        });
});
```

Filtering function:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        $.Isotope.prototype._getCenteredMasonryColumns = function () {
            this.width = this.element.width();
            var parentWidth = this.element.parent().width();
            // i.e. options.masonry && options.masonry.columnWidth
            var colW = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
            // or use the size of the first item
            this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
            // if there's no items, use size of container
            parentWidth;
            var cols = Math.floor(parentWidth / colW);
            cols = Math.max(cols, 1);
            // i.e. this.masonry.cols = ....
            this.masonry.cols = cols;
            // i.e. this.masonry.columnWidth = ...
            this.masonry.columnWidth = colW;
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function () {
            // layout-specific props
            this.masonry = {};
            // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again
            this._getCenteredMasonryColumns();
            var i = this.masonry.cols;
            this.masonry.colYs = [];
            while (i--) {
                this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
            }
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function () {
            var prevColCount = this.masonry.cols;
            // get updated colCount
            this._getCenteredMasonryColumns();
            return (this.masonry.cols !== prevColCount);
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryGetContainerSize = function () {
            var unusedCols = 0,
                i = this.masonry.cols;
            // count unused columns
            while (--i) {
                if (this.masonry.colYs[i] !== 0) {
                    break;
                }
                unusedCols++;
            }
            return {
                height: Math.max.apply(Math, this.masonry.colYs),
                // fit container to columns that have been used;
                width: (this.masonry.cols - unusedCols) * this.masonry.columnWidth
            };
        };

        var $container = $('#container'),
            $body = $('body'),
            colW = 1,
            columns = null;

        $container.isotope({
            // disable window resizing
            resizable: false,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colW
            }
        });

        //FILTERING
        $('#filters a').click(function () {
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what's happening is that you're calling `jQuery.noConflict()` in the first file. That method makes jQuery relinquish control of the `$` variable (returns it to previous value, which, by default, is `undefined`). In your second file you are using `$` which, of course, is undefined by then, and that's why your code does not work.

Either remove the call to `noConflict()` or wrap the code in the second file in this:

```
(function($) {
    //...your code here ( $(window).load() and all else)
})(jQuery);
```

This way, the `$` variable is again defined in your code, but only inside that function. However, I'd stick with the first solution. If you're using jQuery, calling `.noConflict()` should be done only if you have very good reasons to use the `$` variable for another purpose. Keep in mind that when people sees `$` they will think about jQuery. It's almost a standard.

Comment: Thanks, deeting that line solved the problem. The other solution doesn't seem to work :(